# Picture box transparency in vb

Tags: vb.net, transparency, picturebox

When i run my code, the picture box has a background colour, even though I have set the background colour to transparent in the properties window. any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're overlapping a `PictureBox` over some other control and expecting to see through the `PictureBox`. That's not how it works - controls with transparent backgrounds are only transparent relative to their parent, not other controls. You could draw them using GDI+ by overriding the `OnPaint` method of your form:

```
Private Shared ReadOnly SomeImage As Image = My.Resources.blah 'Get your image somewhere

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics

    g.DrawImage(SomeImage, xCoordinate, yCoordinate)

    'Draw as many images or text as you want.
End Sub
```

Also, it seems that people are mostly looking for this functionality to make a game. Are you making a game? Please learn graphics before making a game if this is the case. There are many good tutorials out there.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not making a game, I'm trying to practice a* path-finding for AS3, but am more comfortable in VB.

Comment: Although now i have a new problem - the line i'm drawing doesn't show up over the controls i have on the form. Is it drawn before them?

Comment: @Sam: Yes, it is. To do that, you need to draw them *all* using GDI. But don't worry - it's great because you don't need pictures. (See `Graphics.DrawLine`!)

Comment: awesome, thanks - I didn't know you could do this! I have done a lot of XNA in the past, so this should sort it out. thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Thanks. But is there another way? I want to create a transparent picturebox as a "layer".

Comment: @Jet: Not in Windows Forms… but GDI+ isn’t that bad :)