# Combine two or more Images in Vector mode on PictureBox (VB NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Here, I have made a description so that you can understand what I mean.
in vb.net, to show an image we can use PictureBox.

Now, I'd like to combine them with PNG Images format. 
I've tried to combine them, but if I put some adjacent PictureBoxes on coordinate, It doesn't looks PNG Format at all. Yet, they such as jpg format They overlap each other so that we can't see them.
So the main problem, I guess how to set picturebox according to png format.

Well, let's look at the picture below:

[image: http://i1353.photobucket.com/albums/q671/rizkay/cb_zpsa52ecf4a.png]

Comment: I am not sure how you can achieve that. If it is possible it will be hard. Your problem is that your combination is with pictureBoxes and not with PNG's. What I mean that is different the PNG's background and the pictureBoxes' background. Why you don't try to combine the images at one and then show the combined image to the parentPictureBox

Comment: Give a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342274/picture-box-transparency-in-vb. It may help you

Comment: Thanks for answering, I see, we can use "graphics.Draw" to combine many images at one. but it's a bitmap not vector. i think it's possible, you should try to look how photo editor work, such as photoshop they have "layer" i think it's smart. and why must vector?  if we use method "bitmap combine" after we combine them we can't separate one of them on parent picturebox as they are bitmap

Comment: Yep, the easiest way is GDI+ with its `DrawImage`.